# set view visibility == GONE from another view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

i am new to android development, and from java background , am developing an android app where i have to display of invites which user have got, so the layout will be like below

[image]

here invite response view (yes, no ,  may) will be shown on click of each invite view, but i want the response view to get closed or visibility = Gone when user clicks on another view. currently response views are shown once clicked on invite view.

so to solve this issue, i have added id (inviteId) to each response view as below

```
    final LinearLayout second = (LinearLayout) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.hidden);
    second.setId((int) currentInviteId);
```

now i am trying to get firstly opened response view id when user clicks on next invite view and trying to set the first response view to "GONE"

```
public class InvitationFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<String> eventName = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Long> eventId = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> eventPlace = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EventMO> eventMOs = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<UserMO> userMO = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private UserOccasions userOccasions;
    private UserDelegate userDelegate = new UserDelegate();
    private EventDelegates eventDelegates = new EventDelegates();
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    private EventMO eventMO;
   // private long compareEventId;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invitation_tab, container, false);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        eventId.clear();
        eventName.clear();
        eventPlace.clear();
        // Set Progress Dialog Text
        prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        // Set Cancelable as False
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
        prgDialog.show();

        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                return eventDelegates.getAllEventForUser(userMO, context);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String eventlists) {
                if (eventlists != "null") {
                    eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventlists, new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "total items of eventMo" + eventMOs.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                        eventName.add(eventMO.getText());
                        eventId.add(eventMO.getEventId());
                        eventPlace.add(eventMO.getPlace());
                    }

                    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                    //long totalInsertion = dbHelper.insertUserRelationTable(userMOs);
                    prgDialog.dismiss();
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "total userMos size " + userMOs.size() + "total db insertion size " + totalInsertion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ListView occasionView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.invitation_list_view);
                    userOccasions = new UserOccasions();
                    occasionView.setAdapter(userOccasions);
                    occasionView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                    occasionView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                    occasionView.setOnItemClickListener(occasionView.getOnItemClickListener());
                }
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
        return view;
    }


    private class UserOccasions extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView eventNameTxtV, eventPlaceTxtV;

        UserOccasions() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return eventMOs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // show list values name and mobile number in contact page
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position,View inviteView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inviteView == null) {
                inviteView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.invitation, null);
            }
            EventMO eventMO = eventMOs.get(position);
            final long currentEventId = eventMO.getEventId();

            eventNameTxtV = (TextView) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_title);
            eventPlaceTxtV = (TextView) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_place);
            eventNameTxtV.setText(eventMO.getText());
            eventPlaceTxtV.setText(eventMO.getPlace());
            inviteView.setTag(position);
            View v = inviteView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);

            final LinearLayout first = (LinearLayout) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);

            Button yesBtn = (Button) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.yesbutton);
            Button noBtn = (Button) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.nobutton);
            Button mayBeBtn = (Button) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.buttonmaybe);

            final LinearLayout second = (LinearLayout) inviteView.findViewById(R.id.hidden);
            second.setId((int) currentEventId);
            // to store current event id into shared preference, to compare event ids and close child layout if ids are differents
            prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(InvitationFragment.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putLong("compareEventId", currentEventId);
            editor.commit();

            yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    second.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final String response = "yes";
                    final EventMO event = new EventMO();
                    event.setIs_Attend(response);

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            return eventDelegates.updateEvent(event, context);

                        }

                    }.execute(null, null, null);

                }

            });
            noBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    second.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final String response = "no";
                    final EventMO event = new EventMO();
                    event.setIs_Attend(response);

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            return eventDelegates.updateEvent(event, context);

                        }

                    }.execute(null, null, null);
                }
            });
            mayBeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    second.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final String response = "maybe";
                    final EventMO event = new EventMO();
                    event.setIs_Attend(response);

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            return eventDelegates.addEvent(event, context);


                        }

                    }.execute(null, null, null);
                }
            });


            first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View invitationView) {
                    final long compareEventId = prefs.getLong("compareEventId", 0);
                    final long currentEventId = second.getId();

                    if(compareEventId != 0 && compareEventId != currentEventId){
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
                                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invitation, null);

                        final View inviteResponseView =  (View) inflatedView.findViewById((int) compareEventId);
                        inviteResponseView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    switch (invitationView.getId()) {
                        case R.id.invitation_single:
                            second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;

                    }
                }


            });


            return inviteView;
        }

    }
}
```

but inviteResponseView is always returning null. need direction to solve this functionality. Thanks for your valuable response.

EDIT :-

my layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/invitation_single"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="5dp"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invitation_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invitation_place"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hidden"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yesbutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nobutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="No"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonmaybe"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="Maybe"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout XML. Seeing your code, I think it'll never work the way you're trying to do.

Comment: Also post full java code that is relevant.

Comment: i have added layout xml

Comment: So you're using this layout as ListView item? It's not clear what exactly you are doing. Provide more details such as ListView adapter code. We can't just answer based on guesses.

Comment: this should be handled inside your adapter. You should let your model know that only one invite (model) should be with the reponse active/visible. So, once your model is aware of it query the model to see if one of the ID visible is the ID of the item with the response view visible if so, change the view to visible, at the same time hide the response view in all other visible items. Please post your adapter and how you handle the list.

Comment: i have added the invitation fragment code here for more clarity

Comment: Have you tried my answer? I'm sure it will work as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use an [onFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) ?
First of all:

Set in your invitationView layout `.xml` file (the one which contains the buttons **yes, no, maybe**) like this:

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**Note:** *You must also do this to your parent layout (the layout of the Activity) so when the user touch outside the invitationView, the parent layout will catch the focus.*

Then, what you have to do is to set the `invitationView.setOnFocusChangeListener` to your **invitationView**, inside your `Activity` or inside your `listAdapater` (or recyclerViewAdapter) if you are using it to the invitationView (what I highly recommend).
Like this:

```
invitationView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
           {
               inviteResponseView.setVisibility(view.GONE)
           }else
               inviteResponseView.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE)
        }
    });
```

**Recommendation:**

Recommend you to use a `recyclerView` instead of fragments to make this job, it pretty easy to use and memory usage efficient. Now it supports most of the devices with the [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) that already has a bunch of tutorials, like the linked ones.

Comment: I did not got what you want to set visibility to GONE. If it is the buttons (yes, no, maybe) then I recommend you to set the visibility of each one to GONE, instead of the inviteResponseView.

Comment: After your edit, I can see that you are using fragments to the invitationView, so what you have to do is to put the java code that I posted inside your fragment .java file. Have you did it ? If so, what error are you getting ?

Comment: no error thrown, i had put your code inside fragment, still not working

Comment: Try to put the .xml code that I posted in every single view the user may touch to take off the focus, including textviews, button, layouts, etc

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use some third-party dependency in your project.

As a matter of fact, [nhaarman's ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) can do that very well. Download the [demo in Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.listviewanimations) and check it.

There's a fully customizable ListView that can expand on user click and show more items. Plus, it supports very cool animations. I've used it in one of my projects and it's very good. You can even set the maximum number of views that can be expanded at once.

Comment: sorry dude, there is no need to use a third party library so solve simple List (Model/View) issue.

Comment: Sure, there is no **need**, but as OP said he is new to Android and Java development, and using something ready and encapsulated will reduce lines of code and possibly make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your `BaseAdapter` add

```
private boolean showActionView = false;
private int showActionViewFor;

public void showActionView(boolean show, int position) {
    showActionView = show;
    showActionViewFor = position;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in your `BaseAdapter`'s `getView()` add

```
if(showActionView && position == showActionViewFor) {
    second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    second.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//Don't use View.GONE
}
```

Then in your `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`, add

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         mAdapter.showActionView(true, position);
     }
 });
```

Bam! It should work as you need. Whenever you need to hide all action views just call

```
mAdapter.showActionView(false, 0);
```

UPDATE:

You need to remove your

```
first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}
```

from your Adapter.

EXTRA: To improve your `ListView` performance, you should consider implementing the `View Holder` pattern.

Comment: i have tried your answer, now i am not getting my inviterespone view, and it is not working either